# Elasticsearch java client update by query with wait for completion

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version 5.6

I'm using the elasticsearch native transport client and the `UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder` to perform an [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-update-by-query.html).

I'd like to perform this asynchronously and track progress with the tasks api. The docs show that the parameter wait_for_completion=false is exactly what I want by I can't see support for the on the java client. Is there a way to set this and get the task id back ?

Comment: did you get a solution to this?

Comment: any update on the solution or workaround?

Answer (score -1):

Using the native transport client for retrieving the task api response you have to perform the request like this:

```
UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder u = UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client);
BulkIndexByScrollResponse r = u.source("source").filter(matchQuery("field", "value")).get();
```

The response has two lists of failures and status member you can use get counts. The status is exactly the same status as you can get from the task management API.

Only in case you have dependencies missing, try importing this maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>reindex</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
    </dependency>
```

And adding call this in the client setup:

```
clientBuilder.addPlugin(ReindexPlugin.class);
```

You can find additional information [here.](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/java-api-corresponding-to-update-by-query/49206/2)